# What is recommended way to create modular C applications?

Tags: c

I read in Stack Overflow that including a C file into another C file is not a best practice. I was wondering how can I then create modular applications in C.

I understood that all you are recommended to include are header files, which doesn't contain the code implementation itself but just the "function calls".

How does the compiler know where to find the respective code?
Does it automatically look to a **.c** file with same name as the **.h** file?

Generally speaking, how can separate code within a C application?

Comment: You compile all the .c files and link the corresponding object files together.

Comment: The compiler does not need to know where to find the code, the compiler just needs the definition of the functions (the .h file), but the Linker needs to know. And you tell him! For example if you use certain functions from the `math.h`, you need to tell the linker that the code is in the `libm.so` file, so you give him the command line parameter `-lm`.

Comment: How can I "manually" link two files via gcc command? (Suppose my main is the demo.c and bit.c has the functions I need)

Comment: `gcc -o demo demo.c bit.c` . You may need to create a `bit.h` and `#include` it into `demo.c` .

Comment: Thanks @jovit.royeca Very Appreciated!

Comment: @jovit.royeca can I edit that as example for compiling with gcc into my answer or do you want to make your own? Seems like thats what OP has been looking for.

Comment: @Magisch yes you can  edit that as example for compiling with gcc into your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking inlcuding header files instead of complete c files is best practice yes. Your compiler does not need to know where any other code is, just the prototypes of the functions used.

The part of the process that needs to know where the other code is is the Linker, which is not the compiler, but included in complete solutions like gcc.

When compiling in gcc for instance, you can add references for the linker, as specifically noted in the comments.

Credit to [@jovit.royeca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5226749/jovit-royeca) for an example on linking with the compiler gcc:

> Suppose you have a main file for your program called `demo.c`
>
> You are using some functions of the file `bit.c` in it. What you then
>   need to do is make a header called `bit.h` containing all global
>   variables and function prototypes from `bit.c` and then include it into `demo.c` with `#include "bit.h"` and then link it in gcc
>   like so:
>
> `gcc -o demo demo.c bit.c`

Some complete solutions like eclipse for c/c++ automatically assume all c files in a project will be linked to the main one, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way is to create modules (.c files) with a specific functionality; compare it to a class. To make this functionality available to other modules, you create a header file with the functions, data types and variables the module exposes (makes available).

To create a program, you write or re-use the modules and call them from the main program (to call them, you should `#include` the header files).

The makefile, or a "project" in an IDE tells your development environment/the compiler which modules/.c-files to compile and then the linker links them into an executable.

Using modules as described alows you to hide their implementation (complexity) from other .c-files,

Comment: Thanks Paul. I am creating my C applications in a very simple IDE called MS Notepad ;-). How can I "manually" link two files via gcc command?

Comment: Bracketz, I don't know (don't know gcc) but, as we all know, "If nothing helps, read the manual!"; it will surely tell you how the command line should look like for this.

Comment: @Bracketz I know this might not be possible, but if you don't want to use a full IDE, you could use a coding-oriented text editor, which are very lightweight, open pretty fast and can be used normally, but has extra features. Some recommendations are [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), [Atom](http://atom.io/), or [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Sorry if I incorrectly assumed you use Notepad for its simplicity, and already know about the alternatives.